# Pass value to Channel System.in

Tags: java, shell, ssh, jsch

My aim is to execute remote command through ssh shell.So I used `jsch` to make connection and tried

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
```

but it is not executing some commands like `dir`.

So I tried with shell but could not pass value to `System.in`, as I need to give command through a GUI only

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
```

In the above code I need to pass value through a string from GUI instead of System.in.

So I tried something like

```
String cmd="help";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(cmd.getBytes());
System.setIn(is);
channel.setInputStream(System.in);
```

But even then I am unable to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster provided this answer:

> I did some work and found the answer. I will share it here.
>
> To give input as string in ssh shell, you can use following code.

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

channel.connect();
ps.println("ping localhost"); 
ps.close();

InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
byte[] bt = new byte[1024];

while(true) {
    while(in.available() > 0) {
        int i=in.read(bt, 0, 1024);
        if(i < 0) {
            break;
        }
        String str=new String(bt, 0, i);
        System.out.print(str); //displays the output of the command executed.
    }
    if(channel.isClosed()) {
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();    
}
```